# Why does the assignment operator return anything to begin with?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know that the "+" operator has to return something, and that makes sense to me.

But what I don't understand is why we return an object when overloading the "=" operator. For example look at the following:

```
const Scene& Scene::operator=(const Scene &source){
    if(this != &source){
         count = source.count
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Can't we just achieve the same effect by just using this?

```
void Scene::operator=(const Scene &source){
    if(this != &source){
         count = source.count
    }
}
```

Comment: For things like `a = b = c;`, non-erroneous `if(a = b) {...`, and assinging a value, then using it in an expression in the same line: `a = b + (c = d);`

Answer (score 4):

The semantics of the `=` operator are that you can chain assignments:

```
a = b = c;
```

You have to return an object for that to make sense.

Comment: @LogicStuff - I'm not sure I follow. What are you asking?

Comment: That you *might* want to chain also stuff like `(a = b) == c` - not all assignments.

Comment: I personally don't think that chaining assignments is good practice, but the returning itself helps for stuff like `if (myOptional = functionThatGeneratesOptional())` which lets me bind the optional to a variable and test its truthiness at once. Although I wouldn't do this either.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, you can do whatever you want. I was just giving an idiomatic example.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* return a reference, and that supports assignment chaining like in

```
a = b = 42;
```

… which, since `=` is right-associative, is parsed as

```
a = (b = 42);
```

… so that both `a` and `b` are set to `42`.

However you don't *have to* let your assignment operator return anything, unless you want to support use of your objects in a standard library collection.

Unfortunately the standard library requires that an item in a collection, if it is required to be assignable, must offer an assignment operator that returns a reference to the object.

Also you need to use that form of declaration in order to `delete` or `default` an assignment operator for your class.